# Android Text Annotations wont find annotations in texts

Tags: android, kotlin, text, annotations

I have made a custom MaterialTextView class in which i want to format the given text via `android.text.annotations`. The class is implemented directly into my android apps layout and i assign the text via a viewholder which gets the data from firebase firestore.
In the class i have given an example text directly from the database.
The code produces no errors but it wont find any annotations in the given texts at all. I have tried to implement the code from various sources like

`https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/08d751d843d55b75061039fee4e97931`
`https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f`
`https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithAnnotations`

but i have not found a solution to my problem.

The only thing i have changed is the cast to SpannedString because it produces a CastException see here in my other question [Android Text Annotations java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.SpannedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406786/android-text-annotations-java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string-cannot-b)

here is my class

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.text.Annotation
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.Spanned
import android.text.SpannedString
import android.text.style.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView


class SpannedAnnotationMaterialTextView : MaterialTextView {

    private var mListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun setText(text: CharSequence, type: BufferType) {

        super.setText(processingText(text), type)
    }

    /**
     * Beispieltext Deutsch
     * nach Anamnese, Schmerzzustand und Untersuchungsbefunden\n \n Hochrisiko-Anamnese:\n <annotation format="bulletspan">bekanntes Marfan-Syndrom oder andere Bindegewebserkrankung</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">positive Familienanamnese für Aortenerkrankungen</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">bekannte Aortenklappenerkrankung</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">bekanntes thorakales Aortenaneurysma</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">vorausgegangene(r) Manipulation Aorta <per> Herzkatheter <per> herzchirurg. Eingriff</annotation>\n \n Hochrisiko-Schmerzsymptomatik:\n <annotation format="bulletspan">Schmerzen im Brust- <per> Rücken <per> Bauchbereich (und<per>oder)</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">abrupter Beginn</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">hohe Schmerzintensität</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">reißender Schmerzcharakter</annotation>\n \n Hochrisiko-Untersuchungsbefund:\n <annotation format="bulletspan">Pulsdefizit <per> Pulsdifferenz (evtl. Blutdruckdifferenz > 20mmHg (Arme), evtl. einseitig fehlender Radialispuls oder fehlende Pulse Leiste und Beine peripher Blutdruckdifferenz (syst. Messwert, höherer Wert zählt als realer syst. Blutdruck)</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">neurologische Symptomatik in Zusammenhang mit Schmerzauftreten</annotation>\n <annotation format="bulletspan">diastolisches Geräusch bei Auskultation über Erb'schem Punkt (neu und in Zusammenhang mit dem Schmerz)</annotation>\n <annotation bulletspan>Hypotension <per> Schocksymptomatik</annotation>\n
     *
     * Exampletext English
     * according to anamnesis, pain condition and examination results \ n \ n high-risk anamnesis: \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> known Marfan syndrome or other connective tissue disease </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> positive family history for aortic diseases < / annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> known aortic valve disease </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> known thoracic aortic aneurysm </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> previous Manipulation aorta <per> cardiac catheter <per> cardiac surgeon. Intervention </annotation> \ n \ n High-risk pain symptoms: \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> Pain in the chest <per> back <per> abdominal area (and <per> or) </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> abrupt beginning </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> high pain intensity </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> tearing pain character </annotation> \ n \ n high risk Examination results: \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> Pulse deficit <per> Pulse difference (possibly blood pressure difference> 20mmHg (arms), possibly one-sided missing radial pulse or missing pulses Groin and legs peripheral blood pressure difference (system measured value, higher value counts as real syst. blood pressure) </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> neurological symptoms in connection with the occurrence of pain </annotation> \ n <annotation format = "bulletspan"> diastolic noise during auscultation over Erb's point (new and in connection with the pain) </annotation> \ n <annotation bulletspan> Hypotensi on <per> Shock symptoms </annotation> \ n
     */

    private fun processingText(text: CharSequence): CharSequence {

        Log.e(TAG, "processing Text")

        // get the text as spannableString so we can get the spans attached to the text

        // val fullText = text as SpannedString /* not working causes exception */

        val fullText = SpannedString(text)

        val spannableString = SpannableString(fullText)

        // get all the annotation spans from the text
        // make sure you import android.text.Annotation
        val annotations = fullText.getSpans(0, fullText.length, Annotation::class.java)


        Log.e(TAG, "annotations found, size = ${annotations.size}")

        // iterate through all the annotation spans
        for (annotation in annotations) {

            // look for the span with the key font
            when (annotation.key) {
                "link" -> {
                    spannableString.apply {
                        // set the span the same indices as the annotation
                        setSpan(
                            object : ClickableSpan() {
                                override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                                    mListener!!.onSpanClick(annotation.value)
                                }
                            },
                            fullText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                            fullText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    }
                }
                "format" -> {
                    when (annotation.value) {
                        "bulletspan" -> {
                            spannableString.apply {
                                setSpan(
                                    BulletSpan(),
                                    fullText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                                    fullText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        "bold" -> {
                            spannableString.apply {
                                setSpan(
                                    BulletSpan(12),
                                    fullText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                                    fullText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        "underline" -> {
                            // first underline then resize with x1.15

                            spannableString.apply {
                                setSpan(
                                    UnderlineSpan(),
                                    fullText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                                    fullText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                                setSpan(
                                        RelativeSizeSpan(1.15f),
                                fullText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                                fullText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                "color" -> {
                    spannableString.apply {
                        setSpan(
                            ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(annotation.value)),
                            fullText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                            fullText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return spannableString
    }

    /**
     * Method to bind the OnItemClickListener.
     *
     * @param listener see down below
     */
    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener?) {
        mListener = listener
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onSpanClick(spanText: String?)
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "SpannedAnnotationMaterialTextView"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `<annotation>` tags like that is only applicable to strings loaded from resources. That is, those tags are only going to be automagically converted to `Annotation` spans when loading a string from resources. If you're just setting arbitrary external text, it's not going to work like those examples show, because they concern resource strings specifically.

Comment: Is there any good alternative to annotations via extern imports then ?

Comment: Well, half of what you've already got – creating and setting the various `*Span`s – is applicable everywhere; you just need to figure out how you want to replace the `Annotation` functionality, which is basically just having those `<annotation>` tags parsed for you. Unfortunately, the mechanism by which the platform does it is not publicly accessible, but you could just handle it yourself. Or, if it might be simpler for your setup, possibly devise some other way to mark span types and positions, depending on how you're constructing the tagged strings in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the previous answers, you pointed me in the right direction.

I have made a simple regex to find any
`<annotation key="value"> YOUR TEXT HERE </annotation>` which functions with any given text as CharSequence (i have not tested Strings so far).

```
private fun processAnnotations(fullText: CharSequence) {
    val regexAnnotation = "(?:<annotation )(?<key>:link|color|format)(?:=\\\")(?<value>[\\s|\\w!@#\$%^&*()_+=.äüöß;':,<>?-]*)(?:\\\">)[\\s|\\w!@#\$%^&*()_+=.äüöß;':,<>?-]*(?:<\\/annotation>)"

    val pattern = Pattern.compile(regexAnnotation)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(fullText)
    var matchesTimes = 0
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matchesTimes++
        try {
            val key = matcher.group("key")
            val value = matcher.group("value")
            Log.d(TAG, "Key = $key, Value = $value")
            // your code here
            
            
            
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "no key value Exception = ${e.message}")
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Got $matchesTimes matches")
}
```

UPDATE: 18.07.2021 18:30

This is the complete code with annotation removal after using them ;)

```
private fun processAnnotations(fullText: CharSequence): CharSequence {
    val regexAnnotation =
        "(?<start><annotation )(?<key>link|color|format)(?:=\\\")(?<value>[\\s|\\w!@#\$%^&*()/_+=.äüöß;':,<>?-]*)(?<mid>\\\">)[\\s|\\w!@#\$%^&*()/_+=.äüöß;':,<>?-]*(?<end><\\/annotation>)"

    val frontRegexAnnotation =
        "(?<start><annotation )(?<key>link|color|format)(?:=\\\")(?<value>[\\s|\\w!@#\$%^&*()/_+=.äüöß;':,<>?-]*)(?<mid>\\\">)"
    val endRegexAnnotation = "(?<end><\\/annotation>)"


    // line break
    val brokenText = try {
        (fullText as String).replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")!!)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Line Break Exception = ${e.message}")
        fullText
    }

    val spannableString = SpannableStringBuilder(brokenText)

    val pattern = Pattern.compile(regexAnnotation)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(spannableString)
    var matchesTimes = 0
    while (matcher.find()) {
        try {
            val key = matcher.group("key")
            val value = matcher.group("value")
            Log.d(TAG, "Key = $key, Value = $value")

            // your code here
            when (key) {
                "link" -> {
                    spannableString.apply {
                        // set the span the same indices as the annotation
                        setSpan(
                            object : ClickableSpan() {
                                override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                                    mListener!!.onSpanClick(value)
                                }
                            },
                            matcher.start(),
                            matcher.end(),
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    }
                }
                "format" -> {
                    when (value) {
                        "bulletspan" -> {
                            spannableString.apply {
                                setSpan(
                                    BulletSpan(),
                                    matcher.start(),
                                    matcher.end(),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        "bold" -> {
                            spannableString.apply {
                                setSpan(
                                    StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                                    matcher.start(),
                                    matcher.end(),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                                setSpan(
                                    RelativeSizeSpan(1.15f),
                                    matcher.start(),
                                    matcher.end(),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        "underline" -> {
                            // first underline then resize with x1.15

                            spannableString.apply {
                                setSpan(
                                    UnderlineSpan(),
                                    matcher.start(),
                                    matcher.end(),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                                setSpan(
                                    RelativeSizeSpan(1.15f),
                                    matcher.start(),
                                    matcher.end(),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                "color" -> {
                    spannableString.apply {
                        setSpan(
                            ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(value)),
                            matcher.start(),
                            matcher.end(),
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "no key value Exception = ${e.message}")
        }
        matchesTimes++
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Got $matchesTimes matches")

    val frontStartList = ArrayList<Int>()
    val frontEndList = ArrayList<Int>()
    val endStartList = ArrayList<Int>()
    val endEndList = ArrayList<Int>()

    val endMatcher = Pattern.compile(endRegexAnnotation).matcher(spannableString)
    val frontMatcher = Pattern.compile(frontRegexAnnotation).matcher(spannableString)
    var matchesFrontTimes = 0
    while (frontMatcher.find()) {

        val frontStart = frontMatcher.start()
        val frontEnd = frontMatcher.end()

        endMatcher.find()
        val endStart = endMatcher.start()
        val endEnd = endMatcher.end()

        frontStartList.add(frontStart)
        frontEndList.add(frontEnd)
        endStartList.add(endStart)
        endEndList.add(endEnd)

        matchesFrontTimes++
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Got $matchesFrontTimes frontMatches")

    frontStartList.sortDescending()
    frontEndList.sortDescending()
    endStartList.sortDescending()
    endEndList.sortDescending()

    for (frontStart in frontStartList) {
        val index = frontStartList.indexOf(frontStart)

        spannableString.delete(endStartList[index], endEndList[index])
        spannableString.delete(frontStartList[index], frontEndList[index])
    }


    return spannableString
}
```

Update 2: 18.07.2021 19:30

I have made some changes that are a better approach by not deleting the annotations but to make them AboluteSizeSpans with size=0. So they are technically still in the string but not visible in the layout later.

```
...
                "color" -> {
                    spannableString.apply {
                        setSpan(
                            ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(value)),
                            matcher.start(),
                            matcher.end(),
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            val endMatcher = Pattern.compile(endRegexAnnotation).matcher(spannableString)
            val frontMatcher = Pattern.compile(frontRegexAnnotation).matcher(spannableString)
            for (i in 0.. matchesTimes) {
                endMatcher.find()
                frontMatcher.find()
            }

            spannableString.apply {
                setSpan(AbsoluteSizeSpan(0, true), frontMatcher.start(), frontMatcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                setSpan(AbsoluteSizeSpan(0, true), endMatcher.start(), endMatcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            }

            matchesTimes++
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "no key value Exception = ${e.message}")
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Got $matchesTimes matches")

    return spannableString
}
```